# Can I restore my Linux Mint installation from external Timeshift snapshot after switching SSD?

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, restore, snapshot

I am using Linux Mint 19.1 "Tessa" on my laptop which has 120GB SSD. I want to change to a SSD with more storage.

I know that with the Timeshift backup utility you can make a snapshot of the system either to local drive or external hard drive.

What I want to know is that can I use the snapshot from the external drive to restore Mint after installing new SSD and installing Mint again on it?

Something like this:
1. Make snapshot of old installation to external drive.
2. Switch to new SSD and install new Mint installation.
3. Open Timeshift and choose the snapshot from external drive.
4. Let the program do it's magic and my install would be same as before the SSD switch?

Can there be problems, like the mixing up of old user and new user on the new install (either same user name or different name?), would the restore try to create a new user from the snapshot?

Or would the restore operation overwrite all the parts of the system that the snapshot contains?

Comment: Yes you can use TimeShift, but the 100% working way would be to use a bootable USB with [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) as you would boot externally and clone your system while it's shut down...

Comment: @Fabby Looks like a promising solution, though I probably still need to use that from a external hard drive instead of USB stick (depending on the size of cloned system). Unless I find USB stick big enough.

Comment: If you would only boot from the USB sick and then image onto the external drive, would that be a solution?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Still need to buy the external drive, so I won't be doing this right away, but the CloneZilla thing looks to be more solid than Timeshift.

Comment: Answer posted. Don't forget to accept after it has worked!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you *could do this with TimeShift* but using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) would be a better option as that will clone your system *while it's shut down* (cold snapshot) instead of TimeShift's warm snapshot:

1. [Download](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) CloneZilla live
2. ["Burn"](https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php) it to a USB stick
3. Boot the (now live) USB stick
4. Use the [Device to Image](https://clonezilla.org/screenshots/?in_path=/00_Clonezilla#07_clonezilla-live-image-or-onthefly.png) option
5. Attach the external HDD when CloneZilla asks you to
6. Let CloneZilla do its magic
7. Shut down
8. Replace the SSD
9. Go back to step 3 but use [Restore](https://clonezilla.org/screenshots/?in_path=/00_Clonezilla#09_ocs-sr-x.png) instead of Save.

## Done!